# OneSignal + React Native + background notifications

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, onesignal

I am making a react native app with [oneSignal push notifications](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal). I would like to just change the screen when a notification is received. I can do this if the app is in the foreground or if the notification was clicked. How would I trigger this if the app is closed or in the background?

```
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';

export default class Test extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('registered', this.onRegistered);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem like there is an issue with background notifications and onReceived. Check this: [link](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/209)
Setting content available to true and

```
onReceived = (receivedNotif) => {
}
```

works for me when the app is active or in the background but not when the app is closed. When the app is closed I receive them in the notification center but not in the app.